# Is there a way to tell if my FormView is in Edit mode?

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have some code for my FormView that fires on the DataBound event.  Unfortunately (for what I'm doing, anyway) it fires the same whether it's first rendering the page or if I just clicked Edit.  I need it to do a few things differently if it's being run on the `ItemTemplate` verses the `EditItemTemplate`.  My searches on the subject have thus far been fruitless.  Is there a simple way to do something along the lines of `if(IsEditItemTemplate)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormView.CurrentMode` is your friend

More explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode.aspx)

---

**From the quoted site:**

```
Mode                   Description
FormViewMode.Edit      The FormView control is in edit mode, which allows the 
                       user to update the values of a record.
FormViewMode.Insert    The FormView control is in insert mode, which allows the 
                       user to add a new record to the data source.
FormViewMode.ReadOnly  The FormView control is in read-only mode, which is the 
                       normal display mode.
```

**Sample Code**

```cs
void EmployeeFormView_OnPageIndexChanging(Object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel the paging operation if the user attempts to navigate 
    // to another record while the FormView control is in edit mode. 
    if (EmployeeFormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageLabel.Text = 
          "Please complete the update before navigating to another record.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Huge +1 (on your question) for returning to the question and updating the answer. Seriously, we need need more people like you on SO. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Better use the proper function:

```
 Private Sub EmployeeFormView_ModeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 Handles EmployeeFormView.ModeChanged
```